# (flex mobile)how to hidden the black border in a list when i press left or right keyboard

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, border

this is the black boder :

[image]

and this is my code:

```
    <s:List id="channelsPart" left="120" right="80" top="50" change="onChannelsChange(event)"
        dataProvider="{channels=new ArrayList(data.cloud.channels)}" labelField="title"
        requireSelection="true"
        fontFamily="TwinCen"
        fontSize="24"
        alternatingItemColors="[]"
        borderVisible="false"
        contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
         selectionColor="0"
        >

    <s:itemRenderer >
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.core.UIComponent;
                        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                            //sn.text = String(itemIndex+1);
                            txt.text = String(value.title);
                            //txt.label = String(value.title);
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                 <!-- <s:BitmapImage source="assets/sohupp-login-btn-login.png" width="70" height="30" scaleMode="stretch"  /> -->
                 <s:Label id="txt" width="70" height="30"  verticalAlign="middle"  textAlign="center"   backgroundAlpha="0" />
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

so waht can i do , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black border is the selection indicator that is changing when you use keyboard navigation on the list. I'm not sure you need to worry about that in a mobile application, but maybe it also appears on a device?

In any case, you can disable the default functionality that automatically draws the backgrounds/border on the renderer using the `autoDrawBackground` property of `ItemRenderer`. [ItemRenderer docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html)...

Try this out, on the line where you declare the item renderer:

```
<s:ItemRenderer autoDrawBackground="false">
```

If you still want a background to be drawn, you can add some simple view states to your renderer:

```
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer autoDrawBackground="false">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.core.UIComponent;
                        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                            txt.text = String(value.title);
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                <s:states>
                    <s:State name="normal"/>
                    <s:State name="selected"/>
                </s:states>
                <s:Rect includeIn="selected" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="#FF0000" alpha=".25"/>
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Label id="txt" width="70" height="30"  verticalAlign="middle"  textAlign="center"   backgroundAlpha="0" />
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
```

As an aside, Adobe suggests you use [`LabelItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/LabelItemRenderer.html) or [`IconItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html) instead of `ItemRenderer` for mobile apps. They are optimized for mobile, but not as flexible in that you'll have to write some Actionscript to extend them and do fancy things. Using regular `ItemRenderer` is probably not a big deal, in simple use cases :)

Comment: hi Sunil D., how to Capture the event when i press left or right keyboard , like this name : selectedIndexChange event .

Comment: One way to do it is to add a `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event handler to the list. Then in the event handler you can inspect the value of `event.keyCode` to see if it equals Keyboard.LEFT or Keyboard.RIGHT. It's been a while since I did something like this, I forget if something special needs to be done, b/c the `List` is also listening for keystrokes.  Another approach is to listen for the `IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE` event. But this will also get dispatched if the index changes via mouse or touch interaction, as well as via the keyboard.